# Return all value in my NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I usually use this function to display an entry at the indexPath of my tableView:

```
self.audio = (Audio *)[appDelegate.fichesAudio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Or I do that to display the first entry in my Array:

```
self.audio = (Audio *)[appDelegate.fichesAudio objectAtIndex:0];
```

How can I display all the entries in my array and not only 1 entry? Do I have to use objectAtIndex?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
self.audio = "All finchesAudio Audio clips"
```

Unfortunately, it's not that easy. Without seeing more code, it's hard to say exactly what you need to change but "self.audio" is a single Audio object. You need to modify your app's interface to support the display of all the audio segments at once by getting rid of self.audio and replacing it with something capable of holding multiple audio clips.

Comment: when I use appDelegate.fichesAudio --> fichesAudio is an array containing all my entry thats why I can choose objectAtIndex:0 or 1...
there is no way to choose all of them.